# How to reload the app after flutter localization load

Tags: flutter, localization

I implemented app localization for a flutter app. Everything is working fine. But there's one issue. In the load method of my AppLocalization class, I call methods that return Futures which initiate my translations.

Now while the load method is initiating my translations, the build method of my main page is called which completes the build with old localizables. If I go to another page and come back, the page get translated since the localizables would already have been initialized.

To prevent this, I need to either pause the build method of the page which I'm not sure how to. Or retrigger the build method at the end of the load function in my AppLocalization class. I cannot navigate to that page in the AppLocalization class since I don't have access to build context there.

Anyone has had a similar challenge in their projects?

Comment: Can you share some code snippets? I assume you're following the documentation, and have a LocalizationsDelegate defined in your app, etc?

Comment: Yeah, everything works as expected. I have no problem with localization. It's just that the load method is call and the build method of my main page happens during the loading so it does not get the updated localizables.